# R Markdown : \@ref() not working

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having a lot of trouble getting basic references to work in R Markdown. To reduce complexity from my original project, I've decided to use the bookdown example code, but I'm experiencing the same problem. Here's a link to the intro exmample code: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/blob/master/01-intro.Rmd

When I use Knitr to HTML or PDF the file is being generated fine but the references are not working, instead the file will just containt "@ref(example)". Here is an image to show better the output (my emphasis added in red):

[image: problem]

Direct link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpTTO.png

Here is a minimal example:

````
---
title: "Minimal"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here is a reference to the plot below \@ref(fig:minGraph)

```{r minGraph, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:minGraph}test"}
plot(x=1)
```
````

With the output appearing as such:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rcim.png

Comment: The last comment on this GitHub issue looks like it might be useful: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/62.

Comment: Hi @CristianE.Nuno, thanks for the link. The actual captions of the figures is working fine, its just when I try to reference anything in the regular body of text.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? From the screen shoot it looks like you are using `rmarkdown::html_document` for rendering, not one of the `bookdown` methods.

Comment: Hi @RalfStubner, absolutely. Also, you are completely correct I was mistaken to say this was bookdown, I'm just using rmarkdown. I'm adding an example to my original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want make use of the `bookdown` extensions in a normal `rmarkdown` document you can use `bookdown::html_document2` and `bookdown::pdf_document2` instead of `rmarkdown::html_document` and `rmarkdown::pdf_document`. Example:

````
---
title: "Minimal"
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here is a reference to the plot below \@ref(fig:minGraph)

```{r minGraph, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="test"}
plot(x=1)
```
````

Comment: Could you provide the call to knitr or bookdown::pdf_document2 that would be used? I'm struggling to get this to work from the console in an R session. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyClifton From the R console you have to use `rmarkdown::render()`.

Comment: Ralph - understood, but could you give the full call? I have a problem with getting a bookdown::pdfdocumet2 to run, and am running other MWEs to try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy, `rmarkdown::render("path/to/file.Rmd")` will use the first defined format. You can also use `rmarkdown::render("path/to/file.Rmd", output_format = "all")` to use all formats given in the file or `rmarkdown::render("path/to/file.Rmd", output_format = c("bookdown::pdf_document2", "bookdown::html_document2"))` to specify a list of output formats. See `?rmarkdown::render` for the full details.

Comment: Note to self and others: underscores in chunk names will not work with such references

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I was getting my syntax confused by reading the bookdown guide while using just R markdown. Thanks to Ralf for pointing me in the this direction. The correct minimal code would be like so:

````
---
title: "Minimal"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here is a reference to the plot below \ref{fig:minGraph}

```{r minGraph, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:minGraph}test"}
plot(x=1)
```
````